# Как удалить QTableWidgetItem() из ячейки таблицы

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Для удаления виджета установленного с помощью setCellWidget() есть метод removeCellWidget().
А как удалить QTableWidgetItem(), установлен так:

```
self.item = QTableWidgetItem("Name")
self.tableWidget.setItem(1,1, self.item)
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обратный метод [QTableWidgetItem *QTableWidget::takeItem(int row, int column)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#takeItem)

```
self.tableWidget.takeItem(1, 1)
```

Еще можно попробовать так:

```
self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, None)
```

---

Пример:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


app = Qt.QApplication([])

table = Qt.QTableWidget()
table.setRowCount(3)
table.setColumnCount(3)
table.show()

print(table.item(1, 1))  # None

for i in range(3):
    table.setItem(i, 0, Qt.QTableWidgetItem(str(i)))
    table.setItem(i, 1, Qt.QTableWidgetItem(str(i)))
    table.setItem(i, 2, Qt.QTableWidgetItem(str(i)))

print(table.item(1, 1))  # <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem object at ...

table.takeItem(0, 0)
print(table.item(0, 0))  # None

table.setItem(1, 1, None)

print(table.item(1, 1))  # None

app.exec()
```

Comment: Отлично! Благодарю покорно